# How to pass elements of a list as arguments for a thread in python

Tags: python, list, sockets, tcp, python-multithreading

I am currently programming a server that accepts multiple clients, creates a thread for each client and passes them all through the same function `handle_client`. I am creating a list of every client that connects to the server and storing it in `clients`. I want to pass each client through a different function block and I am not sure how to pass elements of the list as an argument for a thread. So, for example here in my case the two clients are **Robot** and **Iconet**, I want to create a different `handle_client` function for each of the client and then I would wish to pass the client **Robot** through a  `handle_client` function designed for it and the client **Iconet** through a different `handle_client` which is designed for it. Here is the code of the server side.

```
import threading 
import socket 

PORT = 1026
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
HEADER = 1024
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "END_CYCLE"
VITA_R = 'Robot: yes'
VITA_I = 'Iconet: yes'
vita_robot = False
vita_iconet = False


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
clients = []
aliases = []
alias_dictionary_iter = zip(aliases,clients)
alias_dictionary = dict(alias_dictionary_iter)

def broadcast(values_iconet):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(values_iconet)
        

def handle_client(client,addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        for client in clients:
         if client == clients[0]:
            robot_message = 'VITA_R'
            client.send(robot_message.encode(FORMAT))
            robot_response = client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
            if robot_response == VITA_R:
                print(robot_response)
                print (type(robot_response))
                print("VITA received from robot")
                vita_robot == True
                    
            else:
                print("VITA not received from robot")
                vita_robot == False
                   
         else:
            iconet_message = 'VITA_I'
            client.send(iconet_message.encode(FORMAT))
            iconet_response = client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
            if iconet_response == VITA_I:
                print(iconet_response)
                print (type(iconet_response))
                print("VITA received from iconet")
                vita_iconet == True
                    
            else:
                print("VITA not received from iconet")
                vita_iconet == False
                continue

            client.send('LOCA'.encode(FORMAT))
            values_iconet = client.recv(HEADER)
            print(values_iconet)
            broadcast(values_iconet)
            continue


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
        client.send('NAME?'.encode(FORMAT))
        alias = client.recv(1024)
        aliases.append(alias)
        clients.append(client)
        print(f'The clients is {alias}'.encode(FORMAT))
        thread = threading.Thread(target= handle_client, args=(client, addr))
        thread.start()



print ('[STARTING] server is starting')
start()
```

Comment: "I am not sure how to pass elements of the list as an argument for a thread".  You pass elements of a list to a thread with the args= keyword, just as you are doing now.  For example, `threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(clients[0]))` would pass the first element of clients to the thread.  I'm guessing that you already know this and that your real question is something else.  Can you clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary for this

functions_dict = {"Robot": handle_robot, "Iconet": handle_client}

thread = threading.Thread(target= functions_dict[client] , args=(client, addr))

Comment: I am running into KeyError when trying this method